# Dynamicly update scatter/line chart in Chart.JS with multiple x/y grids

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I would like to create a function that I can send data to push to my line chart. My function currently looks like this:

```
function addData(label, xp1, yp1, xp2, yp2) {
  chart.data.labels.push(label);
  chart.data.datasets.data.push({x: xp1, y: yp1}, {x: xp2, y: yp2}); 
  chart.update();
}
```

*label* is a string

*xp1, xp2, yp1, yp2* are doubles

I am running a loop that will execute this function. Nothing happens and my chart remains blank.

I have looked at the [Chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) and it doesn't seem to be helpful for my situation and it appears they have errors in their example code

This is my starting code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [''],
        datasets: [{}]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

This is what I expect it to look like once it's filled in:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'a',
            fill: false,
            data: [
                {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 9
                }, {
                    x: 3,
                    y: 9
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'a',
            fill: false,
            data: [
                {
                    x: 3,
                    y: 7
                }, {
                    x: 5,
                    y: 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'c',
            fill: false,
            data: [
                {
                    x: 5,
                    y: 5
                }, {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 5
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on the initialization of your chart. I think your problem is with datasets, because datasets is an array of objects `datasets[{x:0, y:1, ...}]`. You need to push your new data like `chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: xp1, y: yp1}, {x: xp2, y: yp2});`

Comment: When I try the `chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({x: xp1, y: yp1}, {x: xp2, y: yp2});` it just shows me one big line instead of multiple lines. Any thoughts?

Comment: thank you for editing your post. try pushing your data like so: `chart.data.datasets.push ({ label: 'a', fill: false, data: [{ {x: xp1, y: yp1}, {x: xp2, y: yp2} }] });`

Comment: That worked!!!! Thank you very much! @wayneOS

Comment: no problem, bro. I added an answer to your question for completion. would you mind accepting it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your function this way:

```
function addData(label, xp1, yp1, xp2, yp2) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.push([{ label: label, fill: false, data: [ {x: xp1, y: yp1}, {x: xp2, y: yp2} ] }]);
    chart.update();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access your data and update contents with:

```
chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(   {x:5, y:2} ,{x:10, y:12},...,{x:50, y:25}      );
```

which is easier if your want to maintain the series paint/color settings.